# iOS 15: How to display ATT dialog when the app starts in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios15, apptrackingtransparency

In iOS 14, It could display ATT (App Tracking Transparency) dialog when app starts in SwiftUI as follows.

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: { status in
            // loadAd()
        })
    } else {
        // loadAd()
    }
    return true
}
```

But, in iOS 15.0, it does not work. Apple document describes as follows.

> Calls to the API only prompt when the application state is: UIApplicationStateActive. Calls to the API through an app extension do not prompt.
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apptrackingtransparency/attrackingmanager/3547037-requesttrackingauthorization

How to display ATT dialog when the app starts in iOS 15 ?

**2021/9/28 update**
I solved it as follows.

```swift
struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello!")
        }.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification)) { _ in
            ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: { status in })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: seems like a nice solution - but it does not work (iOS 15.1). Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 14):

Instead of calling app tracking transparency permission in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** call in **applicationDidBecomeActive** it will solve your issue

In **AppDelegate**

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    requestDataPermission()
}

func requestDataPermission() {
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: { status in
            switch status {
            case .authorized:
                // Tracking authorization dialog was shown
                // and we are authorized
                print("Authorized")
            case .denied:
                // Tracking authorization dialog was
                // shown and permission is denied
                print("Denied")
            case .notDetermined:
                // Tracking authorization dialog has not been shown
                print("Not Determined")
            case .restricted:
                print("Restricted")
            @unknown default:
                print("Unknown")
            }
        })
    } else {
        //you got permission to track, iOS 14 is not yet installed
    }
}
```

in **info.plist**

```
<key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>
<string>Reason_for_data_tracking</string>
```

Comment: or if you are using scenes "sceneDidBecomeActive" in the `UISceneDelegate` subclass, as UIKit is calling that method instead of the one in the app delegate then, and also add a delay of 1 second, as otherwise it just returns the `notDetermined` status without showing the dialog

Comment: Yes its the timing issue in iOS 15. For below version its working fine and apple is rejecting most of the apps because of this issue as they are testing the new apps on iOS 15 devices

Comment: This works for such projects only that are created newly. Thanks!

Comment: i think you are missing override keyword

Answer (score 8):

As @donchan already mentioned use the following code:

```
struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello!")
        }.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification)) { _ in
            ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: { status in })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For iOS 15, I faced the same problems and I fixed them by delaying  code execution for a second.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        if #available(iOS 14, *) {
            ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: { status in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.bannerView.load(GADRequest())
                    self.interstitial.load(request)
                }
            })
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            self.bannerView.load(GADRequest())
            self.interstitial.load(request)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A very important addition to all the answers above: the ATT dialogue must be invoked once!
If, for example, inside the advertising manager you have repeated calls to the ATT dialog before requesting an advertisement (as it was for previous OS versions), then the dialog WILL NOT be shown! Therefore, the ATT dialogue request must be inserted directly into the view and with a delay of at least 1 second for its unconditional triggering.

Answer (score -1):

If you are writing a SwiftUI app, you can trigger it on your start screen.

```
struct HomeView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello!")
        }.onAppear {
            ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: { status in })
        }
    }
}
```

Do not forget to add the necessary additions to the .plist.

```
<key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>
<string>...</string>
```

Thus, it will run on the simulator or real device.

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work it. I solved it myselft.

Comment: This is a timing issue, giving this a 1sec delay shows that it does indeed work. This seems to be an iOS 15 issue...

Comment: If you get notification or other permissions before this process, it will not work. You must need write this code block in ATT completion block.